# OneLogin: Connecting multiple Tableau accounts

Tags: tableau-api, onelogin

Connecting a single Tableau account to a web application can be accomplished by using a OneLogin "connector" and following these directions on the Tableau website (https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/saml_config_onelogin.htm), but I can't find documentation on connecting MULTIPLE accounts to my app.

Do you just add a new OneLogin "app" for each additional Tableau account?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the multiple app route is the way to go, since each is going to have different settings, etc.